# Hyperledger Fabric Sample Code Error

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

When I am Trying to run fabcar example in hyperledger fabric I am getting an error

> "error: [client-utils.js]: sendPeersProposal - Promise is rejected: Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: Connect Failed"

As I am new to hyperledger I am not getting the correct answer Please help me with this

I am using :

- Node version : v6.14.1
- Npm version : v3.10.10

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you print the logs. docker ps -a and also for docker logs ca.example.com

Comment: yes I can, The logs show no error

Comment: but we need to know what steps you followed to run the example.Can you plese elaborate little but what you have done

Comment: I had followed the steps from official hyperledger document                                                                    "http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.0/samples.html "   while running query.js program I am getting this error.

Comment: What version of the docker images are you running? can you please share the results of 'docker images' and 'docker ps' please. Thanks